# Customize visualization toolbar in PowerBi embedded editor

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Is it possible to customize the visualizations toolbar of the PowerBi embedded editor? I want to hide some visual (for example all the charts, and leave only the table visuals)

[image: Power Bi Embedded]

Comment: Unfortunately no. You might want to add a [suggestion](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with PBIE too.
Currently there is no legal way to customize/hide visuals pane via API or SDK. 
You always can play with jQuery selectors for hiding things.
As idea just set event handler on `rendered` and then try something like `$(".visual-types-container button").slice(0,24).each(function(elem) { $(this).remove();})`
Plus handle special cases like expand/collapse pane:

```
$("article.visualizationPane button.toggleBtn").on("click", function() {
  var parent = $("article.visualizationPane");
  console.log("catch");
  if(!parent.hasClass("isCollapsed"))
  {
   var showVisuals = ["Slicer", "Table", "Matrix"];
   $("article.visualizationPane div.visual-types-container button").filter(function() 
   {
        return -1 == showVisuals.indexOf($(this).attr("title"))
   }).each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
   });
  }
});
```

Everything can be broken once Microsoft released changes with new UI design.

Comment: That was my latest chance to achieve what I want..probably the only one, for the moment..thanks