# Is there a way to remove visual type buttons from the visualization container in power bi embedded edit mode

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

In power bi service edit mode can i remove some of the visual buttons that are available in edit mode?  I would like to remove around the last 5 buttons that are available.

[image]

I did find this link where someone had a work around 5 years ago.  Was looking to see if there was anything more recent.

[Custom visualization toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148073/customize-visualization-toolbar-in-powerbi-embedded-editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to remove visual buttons in Power BI Service edit mode:

1. Right click on Visual button that you want to remove.
2. Click on "Unpin this visual".

[image]

For embedded report in edit mode currently there is no built-in way of removing visuals form visualization pane in embedded report. You can achieve it by implementing some custom JavaScript logic.

*For example:*

Removed the Matrix visual button from the Visualization pane using:

```
let matrix = document.getElementsByClassName("matrix");

matrix[0].parentNode.remove();
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]